# How to install athena file-manager

Tags: 13.04, compiling, filemanager

How do I install Athena file-manager, under 13.04(amd64)

I tried to compile it, but I ran into several dependencies issue.

I know it is possible, cause I saw a screen-shot at [www.iloveubuntu.net](http://www.iloveubuntu.net/athena-file-manager-shifts-concept-real-code-stage-work-progress)

which was clearly running 13.04

[image: athena-file-manager]

Comment: Actually, I think that's just a mockup, not an actual screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Athena is currently under HEAVY development stage (read - absolutely utterly incomplete) and it's kept on a private BitBucket repo for the time being.
So installing it is not possible for now.

Comment: When will it be released, or when can we play with it!?(alpha/beta)

Comment: I am just the design guy, so I really don't know.
Here is the Google+ account of the developer, feel free to chat with him: https://plus.google.com/107691710289083956125/posts

Comment: Any [updates](https://launchpad.net/athena-file-manager) in the meantime? Also, small typo, "now possible for now".